# Sending content from TinyMCE to Airtable

Tags: javascript, tinymce, airtable

I've implemented TinyMCE on an app I've created, and would like to have it submit the textarea's content to Airtable on button click. The thought process is: retrieve the textarea data, pull some basic information about the user and the Airtable table I'd like to write to, and then create a new record. I'm running into trouble getting the function up and running, though; can anyone take a look at the code below and see where I'm going wrong?

For reference, here's what I have so far:

**Header**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/editorjs@latest"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/airtable@0.11.3/lib/airtable.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/myapikeyhere/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
<script>
      tinymce.init({
        selector: '#mytextarea',
        branding: false
      });
</script>
```

**Body**

```
<textarea id="mytextarea">Start typing here!</textarea><br><br>
<button onclick="sendtoAirtable()" class="button">Create Post</button>
 
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
<script>
    function sendtoAirTable(){
        var data = tinymce.instances.mytextarea.getData();
        saveToAirTable(data);
    
        function saveToAirTable(data){
            var userId = window['logged_in_user']['airtable_record_id']
            var base = new Airtable({apiKey: 'myapikey'}).base('airtablebaseid');
        }
    
        base('tablename').create([
            {
               "fields": {
                  "Content":data,
                  "User": [
                     userId
                  ]
               }
            }
        ], function(err, records) {
            if (err) {
                 console.error(err);
                 return;
                }
         });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting or what are you having trouble getting running? If it helps, from the TinyMCE side of things I can see one potential issue, as `tinymce.instances.mytextarea.getData()` isn't a TinyMCE API. This probably should be something like `tinymce.get('mytextarea').getContent()` instead. See https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.editor/#getContent

Comment: @newso Thank you! While that wasn't _the_ error, it was definitely _an_ error that probably would have caused me grief later on. The error I'm getting is an uncaught reference error (sendtoAirtable is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick), so my function is almost definitely in the wrong place. I'm still running into walls, though--any thoughts?